# How to install xhci_hcd driver after accidentally deleting it?

Tags: kernel, drivers, module

I accidentally deleted xhci_hcd driver after trying to install realtek usb network driver.

I found out about it When I connected the Hub and it didn't recognized by the OS, so using `dmesg` command, I got the output: `[ 2543.191957] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device`.

So I looked for usb2 in `lshw` and got the output:

```
*-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:163 memory:603f260000-603f26ffff
```

Under the `configuration` section I saw that the driver needed for the hub is `xhci_hcd`.

If something is wrong in my research and conclusions, I would be happy to hear.

If the problem is really this missing driver/module, how and where can I get it from?

Is it part of a package?